# rotating a circular object

Tags: android

I am trying to have a circular object that can be rotated on the user touch "rotating it by finger", I didn't find any useful source until now, Can anyone help by providing a source code or any link that could be useful?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the issue the rotation or the touch?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the center of the object and the fingers coordinate. So just use simple trigonometry to calculate the angle that the object should be rotated.

I suggest grabbing the fingers coordinate on ACTION_DOWN and than calculating the moved angle on every ACTION_MOVE event.

All the math needed can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

And an example of handling touch events can be found here:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/handle-touch-events-ontouchevent

Answer (score 0):

[ObjViewer](https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android) demonstrates rotating a 3D model around all 3 axes.

Comment: This ObjViewer forces to close...any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: btw, It doesn't have to be a 3d object... rotating a circle is okay